# Value of type 'RemoteConfig' has no member 'addOnConfigUpdateListener'

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-remote-config

[image]

When working with libraries or frameworks in programming, it’s not uncommon to encounter situations where a particular function, like addOnConfigUpdateListener, isn’t recognized or available.But i try with fresh project it work , i dont know what actually going on

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Comment: Most likely your project is using an SDK version that doesn't have the `addOnConfigUpdateListener` yet. Upgrade your existing project to the latest SDK version to ensure the method exists.

Comment: yah I was tried that but , i used   pod 'GoogleMLKit/ImageLabelingCustom'
  pod 'GoogleMLKit/LinkFirebase' these two pods , with that Im not able to update firebase , is there any solution for that ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but those pods seem unrelated to Firebase **Remote Config**.

Comment: The Podfile.lock should show which shared dependencies could be blocking the installation of a recent Firebase version.

Comment: I found the issue, But I don't know how to fixed, here is the explanation of the situation .When I try to install pod with "pod 'GoogleMLKit/ImageLabeling Custom', '4.0.0' pod 'GoogleMLKit/Link Firebase"
The FirebaseRemoteConfig
version is 9.6.0. But that version doesn't include remoteConfig.addOnConfigUpdateListener {}. this function. So I'm really struggling now.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/12124

Answer (score 1):

MLKitFirebase explicitly depends on Firebase major version 9. See https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/7/7/e/MLKitLinkFirebase/3.0.0/MLKitLinkFirebase.podspec.json#L5.

To use Firebase 10 and its new APIs, an update from MLKitLinkFirebase is needed, or the app needs to drop the dependency on it.

Comment: When run pod installation it automatically gets firebase 9.6.0 so what can I do?